# Skype web controller - Setting up contact id dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, skype, skypedeveloper

I'm working on a simple angular2 application with a Skype chat.  I've followed the steps which are shown in the "Getting started" category in here (https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol) and got it working on my application.

```
<span class="skype-button bubble " data-contact-id="johnskypeid"></span>
```

Using this code snippet, I can contact johnskypdid without a problem.

But I'm having troubles with setting the value for 'data-contract-id' dynamically.

```
<span class="skype-button bubble " data-contact-id={{callSkypeId}}></span>
```

As shown in this snippet, I have a value for the callSkypeId variable in my `.ts` file. But when I'm compiling this, I'm getting the following error message.

```
Can't bind to 'contact-id' since it isn't a known property of 'span'. ("  </div>    <span class="skype-button bubble " [ERROR ->]data-contact-id={{callSkypeId}}></span></div>
```

So I want to know that does skype provide the feature to set up values for 'data-contact-id' or is there a workaround to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried many ways to get this done, but the most effective way was to bind the value is as follows!

`<span class="skype-button bubble " [attr.data-contact-id]="callSkypeId"></span>`

But this config for the skype web control is no longer supported, hence this approach is a traditional data binding method.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the way to go:

`[attr.data-contact-id]="callSkypeId"`

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-class-and-style-bindings